# Laravel 404 Not Found, but image path is correct

Tags: php, laravel, image

I recently deployed my Laravel application to a VPS that I purchased, and have (I think) one final error to resolve. After uploading an image, the image is successfully uploaded and stored in the storage directory, but the browser throws a 404 error.

I have run `php artisan storage:link` on my VPS. I have verified that it indeed is linking **public/storage/** to **storage/app/public/** by checking in my FTP client as well as via SSH.

I should also note, other images load just fine. It is only images in my storage/... folder.

The code runs just fine on my local production server, and path is exactly the same. For this reason, it makes me think there is a permission error and thats why I haven't pasted any code, but am more than happy to share it if it helps. It is loaded dynamically with jQuery so I thought just showing the GET request would be of more use.

**Is there perhaps an environment variable or permission that I have neglected to set after deployment?**

[image]

Comment: Try to apply `sudo chmod 775 -R storage`

Comment: If the pat is correct, check the permission.

Comment: Ok, give me a moment

Comment: No, that didnt work. I ran chmod 775 -R storage on it, and still can't see the images after loading

Comment: Does the `public/storage` symlink have an appropriate read permission for web server group?

Comment: I believe so, let me check

Comment: Ahhhhhh, I fixed it. I will post what I did

Comment: Sweet, let me post it as the answer than

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File permissions issue..

From you project folder run

```
sudo chmod 775 -R storage
```

And make sure your symlink `public/storage` have an appropriate `read` permission

Comment: Thank you for your troubleshooting help.

The problem was that I: a) copied the contents of my public directory into /www aka /public_html, and THEN made the symlink, leaving it in the original folder. I just had to move the symlink over to the public_html directory and it was fixed.

Comment: Idk who downvoted your question but you provided enough data to help you out and well formatted everything so I upvoted it once and its at zero now lol